# pip unable to install Scipy (or anything) (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to download a lib called simpful. But I was just about start to python and I think I am missing something very basic. I searched for some sort of solution online for so long nothing worked for me yet. I haven't downloaded anything with pip before.pip version is 21.3 and python 3.10. I know its just and error log but perhaps someone could recognize it.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1288]


C:\Users\Lenovo>pip install simpful
Collecting simpful
  Using cached simpful-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.0.0
  Using cached scipy-1.6.1.tar.gz (27.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing wheel metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgaetr_j4'
       cwd: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-udpf3ke6\scipy_89c5aff8add94fd794edf96a85737447
  Complete output (138 lines):
  setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-y1pindem'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
  Running from SciPy source directory.
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 151, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 588, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 584, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_fxq5igz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 499, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError(msg)
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found.
  To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
  See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
 

      C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cuph39om\numpy_d591327a7abd4dfeb71a6882dfc84871\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      building library "npymath" sources
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuph39om\\numpy_d591327a7abd4dfeb71a6882dfc84871\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuph39om\\numpy_d591327a7abd4dfeb71a6882dfc84871\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pwa31lhc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m843rygd\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m843rygd\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/ab/e2eb3e3f90b9363040a3d885ccc5c79fe20c5b8a3caa8fe3bf47ff653260/scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz#sha256=dee1bbf3a6c8f73b6b218cb28eed8dd13347ea2f87d572ce19b289d6fd3fbc59 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-87jfigw1\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m843rygd\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'pybind11>=2.4.0' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached scipy-1.4.0.tar.gz (24.6 MB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty fundamental but apparently it was caused by Python being installed twice.

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: It is not justified measure of solving error occured

Answer (score 1):

down to the very bottom of the stack error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

so you need to install `Microsoft VS C++ build tools`.

link to download: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

it's recommended to create an isolated virtual environment,

```
c:\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER> py -m venv venv
c:\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER> venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) c:\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER> pip list
(venv) c:\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER> pip install simpful
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Installing Scipy

SciPy is a free and open-source Python library with packages optimized and developed for scientific and technical computing. If you have Python installed, you can use Python's standard pip package manager, and install it from the Python Package index. On some Linux distributions, you can use your system's native package manager to perform a system-wide installation.

**Step1: Make sure to check Python version you are using**

```
python -V
```

**Step2: Make sure pip is working fine and was installed during python installation(Python 2.7 above comes with pip installation)**

```
where pip
```

**Step3: check whether pip installed is updated**

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

**Step4: check for numpy installed, since Scipy has one dependency that is numpy. if not install numpy**

```
pip install numpy
```

**Step5: install scipy**

```
pip install scipy
```